# Function Pointer for C++

Tags: c++

I am studying C++ on Essential C++ by lippman. Here is some code where two lines contain error while I don't know why it's happening and how to fix it.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

const vector<int>* fibon_seq(int size) {
    const int max_size = 1024;
    static vector<int> elems;
    if (size <= 0 || size > max_size) {
        cerr << "Error";
        return 0;
    }
    for (int ix = elems.size(); ix < size; ++ix) {
        if (ix == 0 || ix == 1)
            elems.push_back(1);
        else elems.push_back(elems[ix - 1] + elems[ix - 2]);
    }
    return &elems;
}

void display(const vector<int>* vec, ostream &os = cout) {
    if (!vec)
        cerr << "null vector";
    for (int i = 0; i < (vec)->size(); ++i)
        os << (*vec)[i] << " ";
    os << endl;
}

bool fibon_elem(int pos, int &elem, const vector<int>* (*seq_ptr)(int)) {
    const vector<int> *pseq = seq_ptr(pos);
    if (!pseq){
        elem = 0; return false;
    }
    elem = (*pseq)[pos - 1];
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    const vector<int>* (*(*seq_array)[1])(int);
    (*seq_array)[0] = fibon_seq;
    vector<int>* (*seq_ptr)(int);
    int seq_index = 0;
    seq_ptr = (*seq_array)[0];//This is the line with error.
    //(a value of type "const std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>> *(*)(int)" 
    //cannot be assigned to an entity of type "std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>> 
    //*(*)(int)"    
    //C2440 '=': cannot convert from 'const std::vector<int,std::allocator<_Ty>> 
    //*(__cdecl *)(int)' to 'std::vector<int,std::allocator<_Ty>> 
    //*(__cdecl *)(int)'




    int a;
    fibon_elem(12, a, seq_ptr);//This is the line with error.
    //argument of type "std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>> *(*)(int)"
    //is incompatible with parameter of type "const std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>> 
    //*(*)(int)"    
    //C2664 'bool fibon_elem(int,int &,const std::vector<int,std::allocator<_Ty>> 
    //*(__cdecl *)(int))': cannot convert argument 3 from 'std::vector<int,std::allocator<_Ty>> 
    //*(__cdecl *)(int)' to 'const std::vector<int,std::allocator<_Ty>> 
    //*(__cdecl *)(int)'    test

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

For the first line in error, I make both sides of the equation the same type, while the compiler says that the value cannot be assigned. For the second line in error, the two same type are incompatible with each other.

And the error message given by compiler is the following:

Comment: What are the two lines where the errors are?

Comment: @MacStation: Search for `//This is the line with error.`

Comment: What are the exact errors?

Comment: @MacStation I commented them in the code. Both of them are in the main function.

Comment: @ruakh Whoops, I'm blind.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice  I commented them in the code. Both of them are in the main function.

Comment: I do not see the actual error messages anywhere in your question. By summarizing, you leave out critical information which we need in order to help you.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Well, this is actually the first time I post a question. I will put these information right now.

Comment: If you are learning C++ from knowing nothing about C++, consider switching to Lippman and co.'s C++ Primer. It spends much more time on the why's and the basics.

Comment: @user4581301 Really thank for your advice! However, I have got a project due three weeks later, so I have not that much time to go over the dictionary-like C++ Primer. I will get to that as soon as I finish this 300 pages' booklet. Thank you again for your kindness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function fibon_seq returns a `const vector<int>*`, and you're trying to assign it to a `vector<int>*` which is seq_ptr.  Change seq_ptr to a `const vector<int>*` or change the return type of fiber_seq.

Comment: It really worked! For the first line with error!! So the problem here is that `const vector<int>*` cannot be assigned to `vector<int>*`. Ummm, Would you please explain it for me a little bit more? Really grateful for it!

Comment: @JackieWang `const vector<int>*` is a pointer to a `vector` of `int`s that cannot be changed. `vector<int>*` is a pointer to a `vector` of `int`s that can be changed. Allowing someone to assign something unchangeable to something that can be changed would open up the possibility that someone will attempt to change the unchangeable. That would be bad.

Comment: @user4581301 Great! Get it! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: If you found the answer, make sure to mark the question as answered.

Comment: I'm sorry, but actually, there is still another mistake in the code. It's calling (the pointer to the function) as a parameter in calling a function. You can find this line in the source code right after the one you just addressed!

Comment: I'm confused, which line specifically?

Comment: @MacStation  fibon_elem(12, a, seq_ptr);